# How to get the base file name from a column of paths

Tags: python, pandas, path, filenames

I have a DataFrame with the column of file paths.

I want to change it to only the file name.

My DataFrame looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sr No': [18, 19, 20],
    'Email': ['Test@test.com', 'Test@test.com', 'Test@test.com'],
    'filename': [r'C:/Users\Test.csv', r'C:/Users\Test1.csv',
                 r'C:/Users\Test1.csv']
})
```

| Sr No | Email | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | Test@test.com | C:/Users\Test.csv |
| 19 | Test@test.com | C:/Users\Test1.csv |
| 20 | Test@test.com | C:/Users\Test1.csv |

1. filename should be only Test and Test1
2. Just need to write Test@test.com at twice *i.e.* once for Test.csv and another for Test1.csv.

In short, my output should look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sr No': [18, 19, 20],
    'Email': ['Test@test.com', 'Test@test.com', 'Test@test.com'],
    'filename': ['Test', 'Test1', 'Test1']
})
```

| Sr No | Email | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | Test@test.com | Test |
| 19 | Test@test.com | Test1 |
| 20 | Test@test.com | Test1 |

I want to do it using python and pandas DataFrame.

I have 100 of rows in the 'filename' column.

I tried using:

```
import os

import glob

myfile = os.path.basename('C:/Users/Test.csv')
os.path.splitext(myfile)
print(os.path.splitext(myfile)[0])
```

But it is only useful for one path, how to apply it to entire column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to iterate through the column, and assign the result to new column.

```
df["filename"] = df["filename"].apply(os.path.basename)
```

or

```
df["filename"] = df["filename"].apply(lambda path: os.path.basename(path))
```

Example:

```
>>> df
   Sr No          Email            filename
0     18  Test@test.com   C:/Users\Test.csv
1     19  Test@test.com  C:/Users\Test1.csv
2     20  Test@test.com  C:/Users\Test1.csv

>>> df["filename"] = df["filename"].apply(os.path.basename)
>>> df
   Sr No          Email   filename
0     18  Test@test.com   Test.csv
1     19  Test@test.com  Test1.csv
2     20  Test@test.com  Test1.csv
```

---

There is also an option using [`Path('C:/Users\Test.csv').name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) from the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, but this is slower than [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) because `pathlib` converts the `string` to a `pathlib` object.

Providing the slash prior to the file name is consistent, the fastest option is with [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) (e.g. `df['filename'].str.split('\\', expand=True).iloc[:, -1]`).

**Tested in `python 3.11.2` and `pandas 2.0.0`**

### `%timeit` testing

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path

# sample dataframe with 30000 rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sr No': [18, 19, 20],
                   'Email': ['Test@test.com', 'Test@test.com', 'Test@test.com'],
                   'filename': [r'C:/Users\Test.csv', r'C:/Users\Test1.csv', r'C:/Users\Test1.csv']})
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

# timeit tests
%timeit df["filename"].apply(lambda path: Path(path).name)
%timeit df["filename"].apply(os.path.basename)
%timeit df["filename"].apply(lambda path: os.path.basename(path))
%timeit df['filename'].str.split('\\', expand=True).iloc[:, -1]
```

#### result

```
67.4 ms ± 1.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
43 ms ± 1.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
43 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
15.2 ms ± 216 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the existing column by redifining it. First read it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_path\file_name.csv')
df['filename'] = df['filename'].map(lambda x: x.split('\\')[-1][:-4])
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

This yields the expect result as a dataframe, so all you are missing is saving it back to csv/excel:

```
df.to_excel('file_path\new_file_name.xlsx')
```

Or csv:

```
df.to_csv('file_path\new_file_name.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the excel file into a pandas dataframe using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("your excel file location")
```

Then use the apply function to perform one operation on the entire column as follows

```
def get_filename(path):
    temp_str = path.split('/')
    return temp_str[-1]

df["filename"] = df["filename"].apply(get_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers you could also use the string methods:

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.split('/')[-1]
```

Not sure which is fastest.

Comment: Then you need to check what the column names are once you have your data frame. It is probably being called something else we are only going off the columns names you provided above.

Comment: This results in `KeyError: -1` because pandas considers `[-1]` to be a column name, so this is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have fixed length of directory in filename column as given:

```
# created dataframe for example
df = pd.DataFrame({'Email':['test@gmail.com','test@gmail.com','test@gmail.com'],
                   'filename':['c:/users\test.csv','c:/users\test1.csv','c:/users\test1.csv']} )   # dataframe

# will create new column with file name only
df['only_filename'] = [(path.encode('unicode_escape')[9:]).decode("utf-8") for path in df['filename']]
```